# Images Save Even When Form Submit Fails In Nodejs Project Using Multer and HTML

Tags: html, node.js, express, multer

I am working on a Nodejs project and currently attempting to figure out how to prevent images uploaded through a form from being saved when the form submit fails (i.e. due to empty fields).
I have looked other several other posts, Google, and multer documentation but have not been able to figure out how to stop the upload from occurring. Here is the code to my repo: https://github.com/halsheik/RecipeWarehouse.git. Below, I have posted any relevant code. Thanks for any help.

```
// Modules required to run the application
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const path = require('path');
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

// Creates 'mini app'
const router = express.Router();

// Models
const Recipe = require('../models/Recipe'); // Recipe Model

// Set up storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback){
        callback(null, 'public/uploads');
    },

    filename: function(req, file, callback){
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
          
            callback(null, raw.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname));
        });
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

// My Recipes
router.get('/myRecipes', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    Recipe.find({}, function(err, recipes){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.render('./home/myRecipes', {
            recipes: recipes
          });
        }
      });
});

// My Recipes
router.get('/createRecipe', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('./home/createRecipe');
});

// Create Recipe
router.post('/createRecipe', ensureAuthenticated, upload.single('recipeImage'), function(req, res){
    const { recipeName, recipeDescription, ingredients, directions } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    // Checks that all fields are not empty
    if(!recipeName || !recipeDescription || !ingredients || !directions){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill in all fields.' });
    }

    // Checks that an image is uploaded
    if(!req.file){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please add an image of your recipe' });
    }

    // Checks for any errors and prevents recipe creation if any
    if(errors.length > 0){
        // Displays create Recipe form along with errors
        res.render('./home/createRecipe', {
            errors
        });
    } else {
        // Create a new 'Recipe' using our model
        const newRecipe = new Recipe({
            recipeName: recipeName,
            author: req.user._id,
            recipeImageFileName: req.file.filename,
            recipeDescription: recipeDescription,
            ingredients: ingredients,
            directions: directions,
        }); 

        // Saves recipe to mongoDB database
        newRecipe.save().then(function(){
            res.redirect('/recipes/myRecipes');
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});

// Get Single Recipe
router.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    // Searches for a 'Recipe' with a unique 'id'
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function(err, recipe){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }

        // Renders the Recipe in its own page with full information
        res.render('./home/recipe.ejs', {
            recipe: recipe
        });
    });
  });

// Delete recipe
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res){
    const query = {_id: req.params.id}
  
    Recipe.deleteOne(query, function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        }
        
        res.send('Success');
    });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Homemade</title>

        <!-- Required program scripts -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Style Sheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/navBarStyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/myRecipesStyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/createRecipeStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Background image -->
        <img id="background" src="/images/foodBackground.jpg" alt="">

        <div id="newRecipeContainer">
            <div id="closeButtonContainer">
                <div id="backButton"><a id="back" href="/recipes/myRecipes">&larr; My Recipes</a></div>
            </div>
            
            <form id="createRecipeForm" action="/recipes/createRecipe" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label id="formSubHeading">Create Your Homemade Recipe</label>

                <div id="recipeNameContainer">
                    <label id="recipeNameLabel">Title</label>
                    <input id="recipeNameInput" type="text" name="recipeName">
                </div>

                <div id="recipeImage">
                    <label id="recipeImageLabel">Add An Image of Your Meal</label>
                    <input id="recipeImageInput" type="file" accept="image/*" name="recipeImage"/> 
                    <label id="recipeImageInputLabel" for="recipeImageInput" name="recipeImage">Choose A File</label>
                </div>

                <div id="recipeDescription">
                    <label id="recipeDescriptionLabel">Description</label>
                    <textarea id="recipeDescriptionInput" name="recipeDescription" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="ingredientsContainer">
                    <label id="ingredientsLabel">Ingredients</label>
                    <button id="addIngredientButton" type="button" @click="addIngredientForm">Add Another Ingredient</button>
            
                    <div class="allIngredients" v-for="(ingredient, ingredientIndex) in ingredients">
                        <label class="ingredientLabel">{{ ingredientIndex + 1 }}.)</label>
                        <input class="ingredientInput" type="text" name="ingredients" v-model="ingredient.ingredient">
                        
                        <button class="deleteIngredientButton" type="button" v-if="ingredientIndex > 0" @click="deleteIngredientForm(ingredientIndex)">X</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="directionsContainer">
                    <label id="directionsLabel">Directions</label>
                    <button id="addDirectionButton" type="button" @click="addDirectionForm">Add Another Direction</button>
            
                    <div class="allDirections" v-for="(direction, directionIndex) in directions">
                        <label class="directionLabel">{{ directionIndex + 1 }}.)</label>
                        <input class="directionInput"type="text" name="directions" v-model="direction.direction">
                        
                        <button class="deleteDirectionButton" type="button" v-if="directionIndex > 0" @click="deleteDirectionForm(directionIndex)">X</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div id="createRecipeButtonContainer">
                    <button id="createRecipeButton" type="submit">Create Recipe</button>
                </div>
                
            </form>
        </div>

        <script src="/controls/newRecipeControl.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to I know of which can stop the upload

1. You can use [fileFilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#filefilter). It is one of the options passed to multer. But it can only be used to check for filetype, etc because `req.body` may only contain fields that appear before the file in the form.

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {

        // req.body is NOT reliable here 
        // it may only contain the some of the fields

        // To reject this file pass `false`, like so:
        cb(null, false)
 
        // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
        cb(null, true)
 
        // You can always pass an error if something goes wrong:
        cb(new Error('I don\'t have a clue!'))
 
}
});
```

```
router.post('/createRecipe', ensureAuthenticated, upload.single('recipeImage'), function(req, res){

    if(!req.file){
        //the file was not uploaded
    }
    ...
}
```

Also I looked into your repo. You are passing `fileFilter` as an option to `multer.diskStorage`. This doesn't do anything. `multer.diskStorage` accepts only 2 options `destination` and `filename`. Pass it to `multer` instead

2. Use MemoryStorage (the default one or an alternative) and only save to disk if the conditions are satisfied

Comment: Maybe add a code sample? Something the person who asked the question can use?